# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine on Ubuntu VPS with all the ram allocated to it

Tags: java, ubuntu, vps, ram

I'm trying to run a file on a vps with 384mb of ram, If I run the file with this command on terminal

```
screen java -jar server.jar
```

It just starts the process but with only 180mb approx allocated to it, I need to allocate all the ram avaiable, I run the command `free -m` and I get this output:

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           384         58        325          6          0         44
-/+ buffers/cache:         14        369
Swap:           96          0         96
```

So I've tried lots of commands with different amounts of ram like those but no one worked, java could not create the java virtual machine:

```
java -Xms32M -Xmx256M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

I tried putting the maximum ram, half and changing values but it gives error.
Before I was running the same file on a 1GB vps and that command was working fine:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar bukkit.jar
```

My java version is:

```
    java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Hope you can help me, I'm stuck with the same problem two days

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I'm sorry I've just found some threads here with similar problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't create the JVM"? Are you sure it wouldn't start and if so was there an error message? If your VPS only has 384M of RAM you shouldn't try to use more than about 128M for java.

Comment: That's what I get as error:

root@vps-dot-me:~# java -server -Xms128M -Xmx256M -jar mine.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Why I can't use the whole ram for the java process? It's just free on the system

Comment: Remember that the system needs RAM, and Java needs more than just the heap space - it will use at least 32M of PermGen space and another 32M of runtime overhead, in addition to the heap. You'll be lucky to manage an Xmx of 128M, and if your application has a lot of classes to load you'll be short of PermGen space too.

Comment: Thank you Dave, finally with this command server worked: java -server -Xms32M -Xmx128M -jar mine.jar Only one more question, -Xms of 32mb is ok? And the -server thing makes any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**java -server -Xms128M -Xmx128M -jar minecraft_server.jar**

**xms** and **xmx** having the same value will allocate the entire memory in one go rather than having to keep increasing the heap. This is more efficient when running a server type app.

As for **-server** argument it's refering to the type of JVM used

By default, all client applications run in -client mode, while a server and certain server utilities run in -server mode. Usually, -server mode provides higher throughput than -client mode, at the expense of slightly longer startup times. Since the application in question seems to be a server type it is recommended to use **-server**